# ASP.NET MVC 3 RC Html.Actionlink not generating link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-3

As the title says...

I have a route (the first one listed) which looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "TopicRoute", // Route name
    "forums/{forumSlug}/{topicSlug}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Forums", action = "Topic"} // Parameter defaults
);
```

I can browse to:

```
/forums/my-forum/my-topic
```

and the page loads fine. Yet I have a Html.ActionLink that looks like:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Topic", new { forumSlug ="my-forum", topicSlug = "my-topic" })
```

And it won't generate the correct link syntax for me? It generates:

```
<a href="">My Topic</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget the controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Topic", 
    new { forumSlug ="my-forum", topicSlug = "my-topic", controller = "Forums" })
```

or use a named route link:

```
@Html.RouteLink(item.Title, "TopicRoute", 
    new { forumSlug = "my-forum", topicSlug = "my-topic" })
```

Comment: Am working against the same controller, so shouldn't need it (I tried with both). Using RouteLink worked as well.